# Equivalence Relation-each eq class is infinite and there are infinitely many eq classes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- Find an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}$ such that each eq class is infinite and there are infinitely many eq classes.

My trying: $a\equiv b \iff a-b\in n\mathbb{N}$ as $n$ is natural number. In this each class is infinite but there are finite many eq classes. *Can you help?*

Comment: You just have to find a way to partition the natural numbers into infinitely many infinite sets, and make those sets the equivalence classes, right?  It may be (I think probably will be) easier to think of in these terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fun trick.

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ by letting $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$. Then the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are the sets of the form $E_n = \{ (n,k) \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, for (fixed) $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Evidently there are infinitely many equivalence classes—one for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$—and each equivalence class $E_n$ is infinite.

Now transport this along your favourite bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Specifically, and define a new equivalence relation $\approx$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by $a \approx b$ if and only if $f^{-1}(a) \sim f^{-1}(b)$. You can then check that $\approx$ is an equivalence relation, and the equivalence classes of $\approx$ are the preimages under $f$ of the equivalence classes of $\sim$. Hence there are infinitely many of them, and they're all infinite!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to previous answers, but easier to understand: two numbers are equivalent iff they end in the same number of $0$s. Obviously this satisfies all of the conditions for equivalence relations; furthermore, there are infinitely many classes each with infinitely many members.

Answer (score 2):

You can take, say, $a\mathrel Rb$ if and only if the greatest power of $2$ that divides $a$ is equal to the greatest power of $2$ that divides $b$.

Comment: What is greatest power mean? Can you write as mathematically? Thanks..

Comment: $n$ is the greatest power of $2$ that divides $a$ if $2^n$ divides $a$ but $2^{n+1}$ does not

Comment: @Tanner thanks for comment

Comment: $1$ is the greatest power of $2$ that divides $2$:  $2^1=2$ divides $2$ but $2^2=4$ does not